# How to decide a new data belongs to which cluster after clustering training data by using Mclust package in R

Tags: r

I'm using the `mclust` package for R to cluster gene expressions data which are timecourse.
I successfully run the `mclust` function for data  `mod1<-mclust(data)` that has less then 8000 rows. For each row I can see the probabilities of the clusters with  `mod1$z` and `mod1$classification`

But I need to decide that given a gene expression profile lets say 6 time points (actually a row) which is not in the clustered data. How can I decide which previously obtained cluster  it belongs?

Thanks for reply...

Answer (score 0):

Your first thought when want to make predictions about new observations based on a model made from other data should be the `predict` function. Most modeling packages have overloaded this function to do the right thing. Same with the `mclust` package. Here's an example using the `iris` data

```
mod1 <- Mclust(iris[,1:4])
summary(mod1)
plot(iris[,1:4], col=predict(mod1)$classification)
pred<-predict(mod1, newdata=matrix(c(6.75,2.9,6,1.7),nrow=1))
pred$classification  #predicted class
```

Read the `?predict.Mclust` help page for full documentation